# Import Large SQL Server Table into Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with over 1M rows and 20+ columns and would like to upload all of it  into Python. I tried the following code, which works for much smaller SQL tables, but for large tables, it takes greater than 40 minutes. Is there a way to adapt this code to improve upload time?

Thank you!

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=ENTSQL01LSNR;'
                      'Database=EMTCQIData;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

StartDate = '01/01/2016'
EndDate = '01/01/2021'

sqln= """ 
select * FROM TABLE_ONE
Where DISCHARGE_DATE > ? and DISCHARGE_DATE <?
"""

INSUR = pd.read_sql(sqln,conn, params=[StartDate,EndDate])
```

Comment: Working with very large datasets will be a problem in any language. The short answer is to not do that. Load only what you need. That is the first suggestion in the [pandas documentation regarding large datasets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html) - which applies to python generally as well. All good suggestions but much depends on your goal.

Comment: Can you describe more what you are doing with the data? Perhaps you can only use a couple of columns, do some analysis, and then go back to SQL to get more details. Another scenario is processing the data in chunks according to DISCHARGE_DATE.

Comment: Did you figure it out? @raven - I have a similar issue.